# Using a variable in tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to use a global variable in other proc in tcl.

Here's a short example:

```
proc myname {} {
    set ::name [gets stdin]
}

proc myname2 {} {
    puts "your name is: $name"
}
```

```
tcl_shell> proc myname

Jhon <--- "Jhon" should be stored in varible called *name*

tcl_shell> proc myname2

your name is Jhon <-- I want something like this.
```

But I'm still seeing this error: Error: can't read "name": no such variable

I also have tried this:

```
proc myname {} {
    global name
    set name [gets stdin]
}
    
proc myname2 {} {
    puts "your name is: $name"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to read a variable `name` that is in the `myname2` scope:

```
proc myname2 {} {
  puts "your name is: $name"
}
```

Of course there is no variable `name` inside the `myname2` function. The variable you saved to is in global (`::`) scope so you can either do:

```
proc myname2 {} {
  global name
  puts "your name is: $name"
}
```

or

```
proc myname2 {} {
  puts "your name is: $::name"
}
```

Unlike C/C++ tcl hides the global scope by default. You need to deliberately import variables from global scope into your functions.